# "exited with code=3221226356 in x seconds" error in VSCode

Tags: c, dynamic-memory-allocation

I'm trying to read a .csv file that contains acceleration data (x, y, z axis). The file format is as follows:

```
BBD66,0.000125,0,0.000875
BBD66,0.000125,0,0.000125
BBD66,0,-0.000125,-0.000625
BBD66,-0.00025,0.000125,0.000125
BBD66,0,0,0.000875
BBD66,0,0,0.000125
BBD66,0.000125,0,-0.000125
BBD66,0,0,0.00025
BBD66,-0.000125,0,0.000375
```

And so on until line 8192.

I created an array `perm` with 819 random numbers, from 0 to 8191, so when I'm reading the file I will only save the line that corresponds with the numbers on that `perm` array.

Code is as follows (code for generating the numbers not included, since no problems on those lines):

```c
#define MAXCHAR 1024
#define N 8192
#define p 819
```

---

```c
  /////////////////////////// READING SAMPLES FILE ///////////////////////////
FILE *file_accel;

// Allocate the array of pointers
char **x_samples = (char **)malloc(p * sizeof(char *));
char **y_samples = (char **)malloc(p * sizeof(char *));
char **z_samples = (char **)malloc(p * sizeof(char *));

// Allocate rows (max length 15 characters, including \0)
for (int i = 0; i < p; ++i) {
  x_samples[i] = (char *)malloc(15 * sizeof(char));
  x_samples[i] = '\0';
  y_samples[i] = (char *)malloc(15 * sizeof(char));
  y_samples[i] = '\0';
  z_samples[i] = (char *)malloc(15 * sizeof(char));
  z_samples[i] = '\0';
}

file_accel = fopen("report_accelerometer_BBD66_80Hz_full.csv", "r");

if (!file_accel) {
  printf("Can't open file\n");
  return 1;
}

// Here we have taken size of
// array 1024 you can modify it
char buffer[MAXCHAR];

int row = 0;
int column = 0;

// compare each perm[i] with the corresponding readed line in the file
for (int i = 0; i < p; i++) {
  while (fgets(buffer, MAXCHAR, file_accel)) {

    if (row != perm[i]) {
      row++;
      continue;
    } else {
      column = 0;

      // Splitting the data
      char *value = strtok(buffer, ",");
      if (i == 818) {
        printf("STOP RIGHT HERE TO SEE WHAT IS GOING ON\n\n");
      }

      printf("Data %d (row %d): ", i, perm[i]);

      while (value) {
        // Column 1
        if (column == 0) {
          value = strtok(NULL, ",");
          column++;
          continue;
        }

        // Column 2
        if (column == 1) {
          x_samples[i] = value;
          printf("%s ", x_samples[i]);
        }

        // Column 3
        if (column == 2) {
          y_samples[i] = value;
          printf("%s ", y_samples[i]);
        }

        // Column 4
        if (column == 3) {
          z_samples[i] = value;
          printf("%s ", z_samples[i]);
        }

        // printf("%s ", value);
        value = strtok(NULL, ",");
        column++;
      }

      printf("\n");
      row++;
    }
    break;
  }
}

// Close the file
fclose(file_accel);
/////////////////////////// READING SAMPLES FILE ///////////////////////////

free(perm);

// free memory
for (int i = 0; i < p; i++) {
  free(z_samples[i]);
  free(y_samples[i]);
  free(x_samples[i]);
}
free(x_samples);
free(y_samples);
free(z_samples);
```

When I run the code, this shows in the OUTPUT:

```
Data 712 (row 6879): 0 0 0
Data 713 (row 6897): 0.000125 0 0
Data 714 (row 6908): 0 0 -0.000125
Data 715 (row 6924): 0 0 -0.000375
Data 716 (row 6933): 0.0
[Done] exited with code=3221226356 in 0.288 seconds
```

When I debug it, it prints out every line until Data 818, like this:

```
Data 814 (row 8170): 0 0 0.000125
Data 815 (row 8176): -0.000125 -0.000125 -0.0015
Data 816 (row 8180): 0 -0.000125 0
Data 817 (row 8183): 0.000125 0.000125 -0.00025
STOP RIGHT HERE TO SEE WHAT IS GOING ON
Data 818 (row 8186): 0 0 0.000125
```

But when it reaches the first free line in here:

```c
for (int i = 0; i < p; i++) {
    free(z_samples[i]);
    free(y_samples[i]);
    free(x_samples[i]);
}
```

After a few steps, it shows:

> Exception has occurred. Unknown signal.

Something's wrong when freeing the allocated memory. But I don't know what.

Comment: 0xC0000374 is also known as `STATUS_HEAP_CORRUPTION`.

Comment: @user694733 Compiler settings won't help. That's a valid null pointer assignment. Any C compiler with max warnings on may still stay quiet. clang does warn with max warnings, gcc does not.

Comment: @Lundin Oops, you are right.

Comment: @user694733 I was about to tell the OP to turn on their warnings too, then... wait a minute... oops :)

Answer (score 3):

This isn't making any sense:

```
x_samples[i] = (char *)malloc(15 * sizeof(char));
x_samples[i] = '\0';
```

This is a cheeky bug, because `'\0'` is actually a valid null pointer constant and so it will pass "under the radar" of the compiler. You actually discard the allocated memory and leaving it as a leak, letting the pointer become a null pointer instead.

You probably meant to null terminate the *contents* pointed at:

```
x_samples[i][0] = '\0';
```

---

Another little work-around to avoid this particular bug could be to invent something like:

```
#define NUL ( (char){'\0'} )
```

It is still a compile-time evaluated expression (compound literal) but not an integer constant expression any longer, and so it isn't a valid null pointer constant either. As a bonus you get a character constant with type `char`.

```
x_samples[i]    = NUL;  // wrong, constraint violation & compiler error/warning
x_samples[i][0] = NUL;  // ok
```

---

As for how to read gibberish Windows error codes, decimal code 3221226356 doesn't tell jack. Converted to hex, it becomes 0xC0000374 and Windows error codes tend to start out with 0xC000... Once in hex we can google it, 0xC0000374 specifically is a heap corruption, which is helpful to know when tracking down the bug.